# Why does the word 'calculative' not exist in the Oxford dictionary?

Tags: vocabulary, word-usage

My friends and I have been using 'calculative' and not 'calculating' to describe a person given to doing or planning things only for their benefits; but it seems like we have been wrong for so long. Anyone with the same problem?

Comment: I have not heard it before even in Malaysia, which I visit relatively often, and where I note you live.

Comment: This is not standard American English, nor have I heard any examples in British English. I see why you might think to coin the word, but it is one example among several of using verbs in place of adjectives, such as *demanding* or *exacting* (to name just two which can apply to a person).

Comment: @Niel: I'm not sure that think + to-infinitive is standard English for 'think it sensible / fitting / a good idea to':  **Collins**: 6. (may take a clause as object or an infinitive)
a. to expect; suppose: I didn't think to see you here.
b. to be considerate or aware enough (to do something): he did not think to thank them.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: See e.g. the [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/think#Verb), #6. This is idiomatic both in positive ("I thought to inform you") and negative ("I didn't think to bring a jacket") forms, as you will find if you search for such constructions with Google.

Comment: Wiktionary certainly gives the 'to consider, judge, regard' sense, but does not say that this sense can be used as a simple catenative. 'I didn't think to bring a jacket' means 'It didn't enter my mind to ...' rather than 'I thought it not worthwhile to ...'. A complex catenative (I see why you might think it reasonable / sensible to ...) works.

Answer (score 1):

It’s in [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/calculate?q=calculative#calculate__13) where it’s given as the adjective derived from the verb *calculate*. The [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/26268?rskey=vVS4bs&result=2#eid) shows that it has been in use since the late eighteenth century.

Comment: "Needless to say, sometimes I get disappointed with friends who do not realize or is not calculative enough to see my ‘generosity’." ...What's up with the "friends who do not realize or *is*" in the link from the oxford dictionaries?

Comment: I don't know. I would have expected _are_.

Comment: Fortunately the author deemed the whole quotation needless to say.